# `await` command causes variable to lose scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am using `await` to pull data from the database. There's a variable `secuity_ok` that is `true` on one line, and then `false` on the next. Can anyone see what the issue is?

Note – if I comment out the line: `let session = ...`, then it all works.

```
Controller.prototype.changePassword = async function(request, response) {
    let model      = request.body;
    var secuity_ok = false;
    var user       = await userService.getUserByEmail(model.email);

    if (user && this.isAuthenticatedUser(request, user.id)) {
        secuity_ok  = true;
    } else {
        let session  = await authenticationService.createSessionByEmailPassword(model.email, model.oldpassword),
        secuity_ok   = !!session;
        console.log( 'A', secuity_ok ); // true
    }
    console.log( 'B', secuity_ok ); // false

    if (!secuity_ok) {
        this.sendForbiddenError(response, {
            error: 'Cannot change password: Application safeguards are preventing this action'
        });
        return new Promise(() => {});
    }

    ...
}
```

Output:

```
A true
B false
```

Output should be:

```
A true
B true
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653408/global-variable-not-updated-inside-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global variable not updated inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47653408/global-variable-not-updated-inside-function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a comma at the end of the first line here:

```
    let session  = await authenticationService.createSessionByEmailPassword(model.email, model.oldpassword), // <--- Note comma here
    secuity_ok   = !!session;
```

That makes `secuity_ok` part of the `let` statement, so it's an extra, inner declaration of `secuity_ok` that only has scope inside the parentheses of the `else` clause.